# How to create a new search form in AEM?

Tags: aem

I have a requirement to show a custom "Assets Admin Search Rail" under Search Forms. I created an overlay to '/libs/dam/gui/content/facets' and able to edit the fields displayed on facets of assets search.

Now when author is searching within my projects folder (/content/dam/myapps), the facet items needs to be different list compared to searching from other folders (/content/dam)

How can I create a new "Assets Admin Search Rail" similar to existing and force AEM to load the right form when openeded from respective dam folder?

Comment: Which version of AEM ?

Comment: Hi @VAr, I am using AEM 6.1

Comment: Looks like you need to customize the whole search form component **`(/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/contsys)`** functionality as the current behavior is not tied up with the dam path selection filter(facet item) to load the remaining filters(facet items), and all the filters(facet items) are individual to trigger the Assets display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this myself by creating a clientlib, using jquery to lookup the elements and manually removing them. Here is the clientlib:

```
(function(document, $) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $path = $("[data-type='path']");
        var $filetype =$("[data-type='options']");
        var $filesize = $("[data-type='filesize']");
        if($path.length == 0){
            return;
        }

        //defined in /libs/dam/gui/content/assets/jcr:content/body/content/aside/items/search
        var ASSET_RAIL_SEARCH = "#aem-assets-rail-search";

        var doSearch = function(){
            //$path.remove();
            if (window.location.href.indexOf("content/dam/geometrixx/portraits") > -1) { 
                $filesize.remove();
                $filetype.remove();

            } else {
                // remove custm properties. 
            }
        };

        if($.cookie("endor.innerrail.current") == ASSET_RAIL_SEARCH){
            doSearch();
        }

        $(document).on('click', '.js-endor-innerrail-toggle', function(e) {
            doSearch();
        });
    });
})(document, Granite.$);
```